# make searchbar with type of search

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a simple search bar in ionic :
and I want to search with (registration number or the name and Lastname)
mean when I write the registration number or the name in the search bar I will get the same result
but I'm not getting this result I'm missing something please help me

here the ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'],
})
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {
  jsonData: any = [];


  constructor() {
    this.initislizaJSONData();
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

initislizaJSONData(){
 this.jsonData= [
    { natricule: "1125", name: "youssef najjar" },
    { natricule: "1126", name: "ala harroum" },
    { natricule: "1127", name: "baha chitoui" },
    { natricule: "1128", name: "chamalou" },
    { natricule: "1129", name: "japa" },
    { natricule: "1130", name: "mohamed ben mohamed" },
    { natricule: "1131", name: "yossra yosor" },
  ];
}

  filterJSONData(ev: any) {
    this.initislizaJSONData();
    const val = ev.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != "") {
      if (Number(val) === NaN) {
       // console.log(Number(val))
        this.jsonData = this.jsonData.filter((item) => {
          return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
      }
    else if (val && val.trim() != "" && Number(val) != NaN) {
     // console.log("2 "+Number(val))
      this.jsonData = this.jsonData.filter((item) => {
          return (item.natricule.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
       })
    }}
  }
  selectVal(val) {
    alert("you have selectes =" + val);

  }

}
```

here the HTML file

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="medium">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="folder/Inbox"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>ionic searchbar</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterJSONData($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item
        (click)="selectVal(item.natricule)"
        *ngFor="let item of jsonData"
        >{{item.name}}</ion-item
      >
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!
I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-htpmyd?file=app/app.component.ts) example for you.

Never mess with your input dataset. Keep it away from filter functions.
Instead have a temporary array and update it whenever needed. Also I think there were too many unnecessary checks you placed.

```
  filteredData: any= [];

  constructor() {
    //move your JSON data here
    this.jsonData= [
    { natricule: "1125", name: "youssef najjar" },
    { natricule: "1126", name: "ala harroum" },
    { natricule: "1127", name: "baha chitoui" },
    { natricule: "1128", name: "chamalou" },
    { natricule: "1129", name: "japa" },
    { natricule: "1130", name: "mohamed ben mohamed" },
    { natricule: "1131", name: "yossra yosor" },
  ];
  }
     

  filterJSONData(ev: any) {
    const val = ev.target.value;
    this.filteredData = (this.jsonData.filter((x) => {       
        if( x.natricule.includes(val) || x.name.includes(val)) {              
          return x;
        }
    }));
  }
```

Bind `this.filteredData` to your html

```
<ion-item (click)="selectVal(item.natricule)" 
 *ngFor="let item of filteredData" >{{item.name}}
</ion-item>
```

Hope it works for you!